Will toasting sprouted bread destroy harmful bacteria like e-coli?
I like to eat sprouted bread but became concerned after reading that sprouts are more likely to harbor bacteria like e-coli and the such. The bread comes in frozen loafs and I always keep it in the freezer until use.
I always toast my bread on the heavy side of done. Will that kill any bacteria if it were to find its way in the bread?
Possibly this question might be a topic for food safety and preparation.

There is a difference between sprouts (as in immature greens you might put on a salad) and sprouted grain that is milled and used in baking.

Thank you I did not know that. The particular brand I use is called Ezechial Bread.

The sprouts are in bread. That is baked.
The internal temperatures of baked bread are well above what it takes to kill e.coli so unless you are adding new populations, there isn't any in your baked bread, whether it's made with sprouts or not.
If you want toast, toast it. But don't toast it to kill bacteria that are not there, unless you have added them after baking.

@Ecnerwal...Your response was appreciated much. Thank  you

Bread made with sprouted grains does not actually have sprouts in it.  The grain is sprouted, dried, then milled into flour.  That sprouted grain flour is then used in the bread recipe.  Baking the bread will take care of any potential pathogens.

@moscafj......Thank you ...you guys really seem to know your food science. I will continue to enjoy this bread it is very good.
